# make spaces between two Buttons in html (no css)

Tags: html, css, web

i made two buttons and margin them to the right to appear on the right side of the page, but the buttons is stick together with no space between them, and i tried to margin 30px e.g. but they both margin together

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; margin-right: 30px;">Login</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="float: right; margin-left: 30px;">Register</button>
```

this is a picture of the two buttons i made

[image]

Comment: why dont you try without the float and you said no css but thats exactly what you use

Comment: i am using a link to a bootstrap css so i can't edit it, and like you said the buttons went to the left of the page when removing float

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` until you get the space you want?

Comment: &nbsp; or &#160; any  will do

Comment: i did this `style="margin-right: inherit;"` to both buttons and i got the space i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using bootstrap. You can use these classes in bootstrap:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Login</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right mr-3">Register</button>
```

[image: result]

- use `float-right` class instead of inline style.
- use `mr-x` class to give margin (x => 1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: thanks that worked for me perfectly, now buttons have spaces and they are in the right of the page as i want them there! <3